# How use break command to exit code?

Tags: python

Please could somebody give me some help on how to use the `break` command in python. I want to terminate the program when somebody enters `'quit'`.

I have placed `'quit'` in the `input()` loop below so when `'quit'` is entered the program terminates - but think it just exits out of the input loop and crashes the rest of the code instead - obviously I am not using it the way its intended.

```
while True:
    user_input = input(prompt).lower()
    if user_input in ('apples', 'pears', 'oranges', 'quit'):
        # the user = int(0),int(1), int(2) values just assign a different column numnber
        if user_input == 'apples':
            col_number = 0
        if user_input == 'pears':
            col_number = 1
        if user_input == 'oranges':
            col_number = 2
        if user_input == 'quit':
            break
        return col_number, user_input

my_col, my_input = get_input(prompt='Enter apples, pears, oranges or q to quit')
```

Error msg:

```
{'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Green'}
Enter apples, pears, oranges or q to quitquit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/MatPlotLib/open_multiple_files_8.py", line 60, in <module>
    my_col, my_input = get_input(prompt='Enter apples, pears, oranges or q to quit')
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Where is `get_input` defined?  Your posted code seems incomplete.

Comment: What does the error have to do with `break`/stopping the program? **Please provide a [mcve].**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment, the issue seems to be that you are not returning anything when using a break statement whereas the assignment expects two values.

So maybe instead of

```
if user_input == 'quit':
   break
```

use

```
if user_input == 'quit':
   col_number = None
```

and add a check after getting input

Answer (score 0):

Use `exit(code)` instead of `break` if you want to exit the program.

Answer (score 0):

To get your program to quit execution I would use:

```
import sys

sys.exit()
```